# Seleção de CheckBox

Tags: java, android, mobile, checkbox

Boa noite,

Em meu app, preciso selecionar um total de 2 caixas CheckBox. Após selecionar 2 caixas, todas as outras deverão ser setadas com setEnabled(false).

Até aí tudo bem, mas como eu vou saber qual foi a caixa selecionada, SEM SABER qual caixa o usuário escolher, e como vou simplesmente dar um setEnabled(false) em todas  as outras?

A lógica seria tipo:

`if(duasCheckBoxQualquer.isClick(){`
     `todasAsOutrasCheckBox.setEnabled(false)`

Se alguém puder me ajudar, eu agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Gustavo, não sei se seria a melhor, mas uma opção seria iniciar uma variável int e incrementá-la ou decrementá-la a medida que fosse marcando ou desmarcando as CheckBoxes com um setOnCheckedChangeListener, e ao incrementar a variável, executar um método para desmarcar as outras...

```
checkBoxClicada.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
      if(isChecked) //ao marcar a checkbox
          {
              valorInteiro = valorInteiro + 1;
              if(valorInteiro == 2)
              {
                métodoParaDesabilitarOutrasCheckBoxesNãoMarcadas();
              }  
           }
       else //ao desmarcar checkbox
          {
              valorInteiro = valorInteiro - 1; 
              métodoParaHabilitarTodasAsCHeckBoxes();   
           }


    }
```

Não sei se fui claro... qualquer coisa, comente na resposta... espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Condicione as caixas antes de desabilitadas...

Comment: If(checkBox1.isChecked()) { //nao desabilitar } entendeu? Com certeza vai funcionar

Comment: Caso a resposta tenha solucionado, marque-a como correta :)

Comment: Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Vamos sim gustavo:)